# How to uninstall python package in win10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to uninstall one package named fp_growth

so I use this operation in command:

```
python -m pip uninstall fp_growth
```

I also use:

```
python -m pip uninstall fp_growth pip3
```

but it shows same errors here.

how to solve it?

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'fp-growth'. It is a distutils installed
>   project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to
>   it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: The command as you have written *installs* a package, not removing the package.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
python -m pip uninstall fp_growth
```

If you are using Python3 then replace pip by pip3

Comment: sorry, a mistake, I want to uninstall package, and your method:python -m pip uninstall fp_growth pip3 show same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `python -m pip uninstall fp_growth` to [uninstall using `pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/)?

The `pip` command, when used with `python -m` (or `python3 -m`) doesn't require a version modifier like it does when used standalone as `pip uninstall fp_growth` or `pip3 uninstall fp_growth`.

Comment: I tried but the warning shows: WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.

Comment: Wait, what did you run? The first line of my answer asks you to use `python -m pip uninstall fp_growth`, not `pip3 uninstall`.

Comment: @sorry, a mistake, I want to uninstall package,I use your method:python -m pip uninstall fp_growth pip3    however, it shows Found existing installation: fp-growth 0.1.3
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'fp-growth'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users\ (Current User Name)\AppData\Local\Programs.
Delete Python Folder.
Go to Control Panel >> Uninstall a Program.
Right Click on Python and then Change/Modify.
Click on Repair Python. Note: This will Fail but be Patient.
Now Again go to step 3.
Now, after step 3, uninstall Python.

Comment: Please go through the proper channels to add/remove packages using `pip`, not this.